# AndroidMediaplayer.create freeze (still running but dont do anything) the App

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, freeze

I was using MediaPlayer to play sounds in my App but from Its start to freeze the App:

Thats the code where I call create method. I moved the code inside an AsyncTask class :

```
public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Integer,Void,Void> {

MediaPlayer mpB;
MediaPlayer mpG;
Context ctx;

BackgroundSound(Context appctx)
{
    ctx = appctx;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Integer... Params) {
    switch (Params[0]){
        case 0:
            mpB = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.sonidoemocion5sec);
            mpB.setLooping(true);
            mpB.setVolume(0.75f, 0.75f);
            mpB.start();
            break;
        case 1:
            if (mpG != null)
            {
                mpG.release();
                mpG = null;
            }
            mpG = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.ganador);
            mpG.setVolume(1, 1);
            mpG.start();
            break;
        case 2:
            if (mpG != null){
                mpG.release();
                mpG = null;
            }
            mpG = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.perder);
            mpG.setVolume(1, 1);
            mpG.start();
            break;
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Debuging I find that the freeze (app still running but dont make anything) occurred in the new line inside the method create from MediaPlayer.java file::

```
public static MediaPlayer create(Context context, Uri uri, SurfaceHolder holder,
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes, int audioSessionId) {

    try {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
```

I don't understand what's going on. Any tips?

The warn & Error Log exits:

[image]

Comment: Ideally, you should operate with the `MediaPlayer` in a service so that it happens in the background. Seeing just this much code, I suspect it is because of the `MediaPlayer` object.

Comment: I just move into a Asyntask but still freezing when attempt to execute the "new" instruction without getting any error mgs @Pulak

Comment: Can you show us the logs when the freeze has

Comment: From where you are playing player? Means from which method?

Comment: From doInBackground () method of the Asyntask class. I start playing just after cleated the mediaplayer with the sound to play @Vickyexpert

Comment: I've added the Warn and Error log right after execute the instrucation. Hope its help. In the other hand I'm starting to think that Its a infinity loop and not that the App freeze. @Pulak

Comment: @DanielSuarezGarcía The logs aren't helping. Can you edit the question and update the code after you put it in the AsyncTask? I don't see any loop in the code so can't comment if it's an infinite loop. Have you tried using a service?

Comment: Added the new code (inside the AsyncTask). @Pulak. In other hand I create a new proyect, just to see If a made a change in the first proyect that I cant recall and maybe that its causing the problem. The result of executing the second proyect is the same malfunction.

Comment: @DanielSuarezGarcía I've added an answer, try it out

Comment: @DanielSuarezGarcía you can check my answer and implement in your code

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `MediaPlayer.create()`, use `mp.setDataSource()` method so that you can call `mp.prepareAsync()` and then set listener to listen for its completion like this:

```
mp.setDataSource(this, audioUri);
mp.prepareAsync();
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
```

Now for this `audioUri` object of `Uri`, you can set it to your audio files in the `raw` folder by having this line of code in your project:

```
audioUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.yourpackagename/" + R.raw.your_audiofile_name);
```

This method prepares the `mp` asynchronously and doesn't block the UI

Comment: Thanks for the response @Pulak but the "new MediaPlayer()" instruction keep working without returning memory address. I just openen a bug report.

Answer (score 0):

There are **two** possible solutions for this issue, but it is not sure that it will work properly as I have not tested it.

**Solution 1.**

Replace below line:

```
audiojuego = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sonidoemocion);
```

with:

```
audiojuego = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sonidoemocion);
//As you are calling from doInBackground() method, this will not work properly.
```

**Solution 2.**

Initialize media player by your own way instead of default.

```
Uri url=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/sonidoemocion");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
mediaPlayer.prepare(); // might take long! (for buffering, etc)
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the "new MediaPlayer()" instruction keep doing nothing and dont return the memory address for the MediaPlayer variable. I just opened a bug repot in Android development.

Comment: @DanielSuarezGarcía did you get any solution or not yet?

Comment: not as usual. The trouble seems to stop I dont change anything, but the audio start to work again. Just surprising as the audio stop to work.